# What is an insightful proof ( not a verification ) of the Quadratic Reciprocity Law?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Helmut Koch wrote in "Introduction to classical mathematics" (Springer,  1986) about the Quadratic Reciprocity Law: "... Altogether Gauss gave seven proofs of this theorem, however they should all be regarded as verifications, which give no insight into the background of the law." - The number of different proofs of Quadratic Reciprocity is overwhelming and is still growing, see: http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/rchrono.html

What is an -insightful- and illuminating proof of the Quadratic Reciprocity Law, if not the most illuminating one in your perception? ( I have seen this answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1420/whats-the-best-proof-of-quadratic-reciprocity but there the op asks for an easy to understand proof. )

Comment: The question appears to me to be vague.

Comment: I find Zolotarev's proof to be the clearest of the ones I have seen. But there is no clear-cut border between "insightful" proofs and verifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A proof that really gets to the heart of the matter is the proof based on Frobenius elements of the Galois groups of cyclotomic fields. [Here is an exposition of it  on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_quadratic_reciprocity#Proof_using_algebraic_number_theory).

If you aren't familiar with the material needed to understand this proof, Marcus's *Number Fields* is a good resource; the proof of quadratic reciprocity occurs there on page 107.

Comment: Sadly that book of Marcus is not typeset ( traditionally or LaTeX. ) Makes it very hard to read, for me anyway.